# Executing Openstack CLI commands from within a Python script and writing the results

Tags: python, openstack, gitlab-ci

The task I have at hand is to make a python script that checks the status of a gitlab-ci pipeline and what runner and flavor it's using. This is my code:

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import os

#Authorization
os.system("curl -H "Private-Token: censored" https://git.censored.com/censored/Test33004__half")

#Get json of the project pipelines and covert it to text
res = requests.get('https://git.censored.com/censored/Test33004__half/pipelines')
data = response.json(res.text)

#Main login and actions
if: element['status'] == "active"
    print element['status']
    #Here we will put the runner checking actions
    #nova list
    #openstack flavor list
else:
    print element['status']
```

To denote, I am not entirely sure that what I have up to this point is in any way functional but I'm really trying lol. My question is about the runner checking actions. In comments I've put the commands I need to execute (in OpenstackCLI) to recieve the information I need about the runner but I don't know how to do that within a python script. I'd greatly appreciate any help with that and also how I'd store the information the commands retrieve.